# C++ program to remove repeated letters, not working for just one case

Tags: c++, string

This program checks the string from position 0 to position (size of the string - 1) to check if for any position between that, contains repeated letters, and if it does then it deletes that letter.

This works for all the cases except: RRRRR

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    for(int i=0; i<s.size()-1; i++){
       if(s.at(i)==s.at(i+1)){
           s.erase(i,1);
           i=0;
       }
    }
    cout<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you are at `size()-1` you access an invalid element

Comment: Covered by the `at` method if it could happen. `i<s.size()-1` says it won't, but will screw up if given an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You reset the index to 1 for any repeated char. In case if RRR is reached, you remove the 3rd R, then the index becomes 1 and the loop stops: 1 < 2-1 is false.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    for(int i=0; !s.empty() && i<s.size()-1;){
       if(s.at(i)==s.at(i+1))
           s.erase(i,1);
       else
           i++;
    }
    cout<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```